# How to Backup a Log-shipped Mirror Database without breaking log-shipping

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I’ve currently got a slow connection between LIVE and DR data-centres (new pipe is 6 months away).

Databases are log-shipped every 15 minutes.

My problem is that at the weekend the FULL BACKUPS take 3 days to copy over to DR.

I’m trying to find a way to take the Weekly Full Backups directly off the log-shipping Mirror.

I’m limited to switching the Mirror databases between “No Recovery” & “Standby” and I can’t take the Mirror DB off-line.

Has anyone figured out how to do this without breaking Log-shipping? I’m guessing it needs to have the database in Standby Mode. I’ve experimented with “WITH COPY-ONLY” but this needed the database to be in “recovery”.

Is there a third party tool? Please help.

Comment: If the DB is log-shipped every 15 mins, why are you also copying the full backup?  Is it another layer of redundancy ?

Comment: If the live data-centre has a catastrophic failure then the business will move to DR, but the DBAs will want to grab a full backup of all databases on DR, consequently the RTO is impacted. Having full backups with diffs will remove the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not possible to take a backup of a secondary log-shipped DB without bringing it online.  I believe to take a backup with log shipping, the secondary DB has to be brought online `WITH RECOVERY` as Standby/Read-Only won't allow the DB to be backed up.

Other sources that confirm:

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/41d80415-80bc-4821-85b1-762ce9ea72f1/how-to-backup-the-log-shipping-secondary-database?forum=sqldatabaseengine

[Can I backup (Full) the Log-Shipping Secondary Database?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/100525/can-i-backup-full-the-log-shipping-secondary-database)

Comment: One thing to consider is configuring DFS between your log shipping primary and log shipping secondary.  You can throttle the bandwidth with DFS and it is pretty hands-free after setup and configuration.  Talk to one of your sysadmins in your infrastructure department to see if that is a feasible solution.